# Find midpoint between two points on a sphere

Tags: math, geometry

I have a sphere with `radius=1` centered on the `origin=(0, 0, 0)`. On this sphere, I have several points that I know (see picture). Now I want to find new points according to this rule:

A new point is given by bisecting the distance between two points **on the sphere**.

In this example (see picture), we could assume that I want to find the midpoint between "FT7" and "FCz". I have the xyz (and spherical) coordinates of "FT7" and "FCz".

According to my previous research, this might involve computing the [great circle distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance) ... to then find the midpoint on the resulting arc. But I am at a loss how to do even that and whether it would be the right approach at all.

Lastly, this question might be more adequately posed on some math site, but I am hoping for a computational and intuitive approach to solving the problem.

[image: sphere example image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One easy way to find your "midpoint" is this two-step process:

1. Calculate the actual midpoint of the line segment joining the two given points. If the two points are not on opposite sides of the sphere, this midpoint will not be the origin and will be inside the sphere.
2. Normalize that point to shift it farther away from the origin and onto the sphere.

If your two points are `(x1, y1, z1)` and `(x2, y2, z2)`, the midpoint is

```
((x1+x2)/2, (y1+y2)/2, (z1+z2)/2)
```

Let's call that `(x3, y3, z3)`. The distance of that point from the origin is `sqrt(x3^2 + y3^2 + z3^2)`--let's call that `L`.If that point was the origin, `L` is zero and there is no "midpoint" by your definition. Otherwise, your desired "midpoint" is

```
(x3/L, y3/L, x3/L)
```

since your sphere has radius `1`. If the radius were something else, multiply those coordinates by the radius. Some programming languages can make that calculation simpler--some have a normalization function already available.

Comment: If you are going to normalize anyway, you can save yourself from three unnecessary divisions by choosing (x3, y3, z3) as ((x1+x2), (y1+y2), (z1+z2)), and then normalizing that.