# How to calculate intersection coordinate between two given geo coordinates and bearing angle

Tags: c++, c, math, intersection, coordinate-systems

I want to calculate the intersect point of following coordinates. I am able to calculate the bearing angle i.e. heading and distance between these two coordinates. But not get how to calculate intersect point of coordinates.

```
 QGeoCoordinate  sourceCoord(19.999601675,73.726176879);
 QGeoCoordinate destinationCoord(19.999139102,73.725825826);

   distance = 0.06318 km
   bearing angle (heading) 1 to 2 = 215
   bearing angle (heading) 2 to 1 = 35
```

To calculate distance i am using this formula:

//φ is latitude, λ is longitude, R is earth’s radius

`a = sin²(Δφ/2) + cos φ1 ⋅ cos φ2 ⋅ sin²(Δλ/2)`

// distance between two coordinates

`c = 2 ⋅ atan2( √a, √(1−a) )`

`d = R ⋅ c`

To calculate bearing angle(heading) I used formula:

`θ = atan2( sin Δλ ⋅ cos φ2 , cos φ1 ⋅ sin φ2 − sin φ1 ⋅ cos φ2 ⋅ cos Δλ )`

How to calculate intersect point between two geo coordinates from bearing angle and heading?

Comment: Have you considered converting to a Mercator projection (e.g. UTM), then compute the intersection and then revert back to spherical coordinates?

Comment: Convert (R, φ1, λ1) to (x1,y1,z1) and (R, φ2, λ2) to (x2,y2,z2). Average the (x,y,z) values.  Convert average to  (R, φ3, λ3).  You may need to walk through the Earth though.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming

Comment: I don't quite get what you are asking about. :( I suppose I understand an intersection of lines – but no idea what an 'intersection of coordinates' is. Do you possibly mean an intersection of two lines, protruding from two points (given by coordinates) in given directions?

Answer (score 0):

This question has mostly been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50451331/find-midpoint-between-two-points-on-a-sphere).

If you assume the earth is spherical, you can do something similar to what [@chux - Reinstate Monica](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2410359/chux-reinstate-monica) suggested:

- convert to cartesian coordinates
- add the points
- convert the result to lat/long, ignoring radius

In Python, it might look something like this (I got rid of the `math.`s to make it easier to read):

```py
def midpt(lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2):
    if lat1 == -lat2 and abs(lng1 - lng2) == 180:
        return [0, (radians(lng1) + radians(lng2)) / 2]
    # convert to cartesian
    cart1 = [cos(radians(lat1)) * cos(radians(lng1)),
             cos(radians(lat1)) * sin(radians(lng1)),
             sin(radians(lat1))
             ]
    cart2 = [cos(radians(lat2)) * cos(radians(lng2)),
             cos(radians(lat2)) * sin(radians(lng2)),
             sin(radians(lat2))
             ]
    # add the positions
    pt_sum = [cart1[0] + cart2[0],
              cart1[1] + cart2[1],
              cart1[2] + cart2[2],
              ]
    r = sqrt(pt_sum[0] ** 2 + pt_sum[1] ** 2 + pt_sum[2] ** 2)
    # convert back to lat/lng
    int_lat = degrees(asin(pt_sum[2]/r))
    int_lng = degrees(atan2(pt_sum[1], pt_sum[0]))
    return [int_lat, int_lng]
```